# Bundler Error Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, webpack

Trying to get my bundler to compile. However, I am getting this error [[image: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.]Heres my webpack.config.js file.

**this is what the terminal says**

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'rules'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, infrastructureLogging?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           rules: …
         }
       })
```

[[image: Heres my second file]Here's my file structure as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ZeP.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6ZeP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Webpack doesn't deal with es6, so you have to add babel. Babel turns es6 into es5. Here's a link to my repo where I do a detailed Readme on setting up webpack with babel in an vanilla javascript project.

https://github.com/joeygaitan/breakout